# storing incremented checkbox (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a custom checkbox that increments on click. Everything works fine except I can't figure out how to store the incremented value. This is what I have so far:

```js
var clicks = 0;
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
  clicks++;
  $('.clickspan').html(clicks);
});
parseInt(document.getElementById('checkbox1').value = clicks)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='array[]' id='checkbox1' value=''>
<div class='count'><span class='clickspan'></span></div>
```

`print_r($array)` gives me 0. I somehow should be able to store the incremented total in a new variable and use that to send back to the value field like this:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('checkbox1').value = totalclicks)
```

But how can I store "totalclicks"?

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the value of the checkbox on load *only. You need to do that *inside* the click handler. You can also remove the `parseInt()`, because, aside from being in the wrong place, it's redundant

Comment: you want checkbox value or value of click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value of the checkbox on load *only*. You need to do that *inside* the click handler. You can also remove the `parseInt()`, because, aside from being in the wrong place, it's redundant

```js
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    $('.clickspan').html(++v);
    return v;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="array[]" id="checkbox1" value="0">
<div class="count"><span class="clickspan"></span></div>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote/accept an answer if it helped

Comment: sure, there's a certain time limit in order to do so :)

Comment: is there a way to leave the checkbox on once it is clicked once? Now when the click value is even (checkbox off), the value is not stored inside the array.

Comment: There is, but that's not how checkboxes should work. I'm not sure exactly what behaviour you want this to have. I'd suggest possibly using a button to do the incrementing instead.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, the problem is that I want it to remain checked once it is pushed once. A button does't really act like a switch, a checkbox does. Besides that I have a working css that is built completely on checkboxes, altering all that to work with buttons will cost me a lot more time, so IF there would be a way to solve this with checkboxes i'd prefer that obviously.